# in destination folder uploaded file is not store in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

controller.js

```
var multer = require('multer');

var upload = (req, res) => {
    var doc = req.files.file;
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination:(req,files, cb)=> {
          cb(null, '/uploads')
        },
        filename:(req,files, cb) => {
            var datetimestamp = Date.now();
            cb(null, uploadDoc.originalname);

        }
      })

      var upload = multer({
        storage: multer.memoryStorage()
    }).single('file')


    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            res.json({ error_code: 1, err_desc: err });
            return;
        }
        res.json({'msg': 'File uploaded successfully!', 'file': req.files.file});


    });
};

module.exports={ upload:upload}
```

router.js

```
var express =require("express");
var Router = express.Router();

var Controller = require('../Controllers/Ucontrollers');

Router.route('/upload/file').post(Controller.mediaUpload);

module.exports =Router;
```

in Postman showing results:

```
{
    "msg": "File uploaded successfully!",
    "file": {
        "fieldName": "file",
        "originalFilename": "doc.pdf",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\zwruODmEBT-iWFT0_zDJt8-y.pdf",
        "headers": {
            "content-disposition": "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"doc.pdf\"",
            "content-type": "application/pdf"
        },
        "size": 292202,
        "name": "doc.pdf",
        "type": "application/pdf"
    }
}
```

however in destination folder nothing inside the document.In postman getting result sucessfully but in upload folder not stored.

I tried everthing but document is not stored in the destination.Where i did mistake here.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: while dubuging i didn't get error

Comment: And what have you tried? Debugging code is not about reading error messages, but about following the execution

Comment: ok .where i did mistake in this code?

Comment: I don't know, but that's what debugging would show. Why don't you step through the code to see what happens where? And after the comment in the answer, are you sure that the file is not stored at the given path?

Comment: sure the file is not store in given path

Answer (score 0):

From the response, you can understand that the file is stored in temp folder.

```
{
    "msg": "File uploaded successfully!",
    "file": {
        "fieldName": "file",
        "originalFilename": "doc.pdf",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\zwruODmEBT-iWFT0_zDJt8-y.pdf",
        "headers": {
            "content-disposition": "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"doc.pdf\"",
            "content-type": "application/pdf"
        },
        "size": 292202,
        "name": "doc.pdf",
        "type": "application/pdf"
    }
}
```

The problem is, you are not using disk storage. Simply do the following change in `controller.js`

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
}).single('file')
```

Comment: if destination folder is not there then only it will store in temp folder.However i created destination folder also .this one also not work

Comment: why the file is not stored in specified path

Comment: And one more thing req.files having file details but for me only coming like this.

Comment: someone please  help me

Comment: Actually i uninstall everything after that i install ,then it's working